# Creating an XsrfProtectedServiceServlet with a @Service stereotype throws a NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, gwt, csrf

I am trying to add CSRF protection to our GWT RPC layer as per the guide in the
[GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideSecurityRpcXsrf.html) documentation.

I am having issues with creating my RPC service implementation bean, that extends `XsrfProtectedServiceServlet`, because it seems the context
configuration is only created after the bean creation. I get the following NullPointerException when attempting to run
the application:

```
ERROR [ContextLoader] : Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myServiceImpl' defined in file
[/path/to/project/exploded/WEB-INF/classes/za/co/example/server/MyServiceImpl.class]:
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
.
.
.
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.XsrfProtectedServiceServlet.init(XsrfProtectedServiceServlet.java:84)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1713)
  at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1650)
  at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579)
```

Here is what the server-side implementation of the RPC service looks like:

```
import com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.XsrfProtectedServiceServlet;

@Service
public class MyServiceImpl extends XsrfProtectedServiceServlet implements MyService {
    // interface overriding methods
}
```

And this is the client-side interface:

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.XsrfProtectedService;

public interface MyService extends XsrfProtectedService {
    // interface methods
}
```

Note: I've omitted `MyServiceAsync` seeing as no code change had to be made there to implement the anti-CSRF token in our RPC calls.

The null pointer is being thrown when the `XsrfProtectedServiceServlet` attempts to access the servlet config through `getServletConfig()` as seen below i.e the return value for `getServletConfig()` is null:

```
@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {
    super.init();
    // do not overwrite if value is supplied in constructor
    if (sessionCookieName == null) {
        // servlet configuration precedes context configuration
        sessionCookieName = getServletConfig().getInitParameter(
                XsrfTokenServiceServlet.COOKIE_NAME_PARAM);
        if (sessionCookieName == null) {
            sessionCookieName = getServletContext().getInitParameter(
                    XsrfTokenServiceServlet.COOKIE_NAME_PARAM);
        }
        if (sessionCookieName == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    XsrfTokenServiceServlet.COOKIE_NAME_NOT_SET_ERROR_MSG);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there additional configuration I need to do in order to have my RPC service implementation injected correctly by Spring using the `@Service` stereotype?

Comment: Add @Service to MyService  as well

Comment: Hey @SundararajGovindasamy, thanks for your suggestion. I tried that and still get the same errors on startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code of the class throwing the nullpointer, this seems to be the method in question:

```
@Override
  public void init() throws ServletException {
    super.init();
    // do not overwrite if value is supplied in constructor
    if (sessionCookieName == null) {
      // servlet configuration precedes context configuration
      sessionCookieName = getServletConfig().getInitParameter(
          XsrfTokenServiceServlet.COOKIE_NAME_PARAM);
      if (sessionCookieName == null) {
        sessionCookieName = getServletContext().getInitParameter(
            XsrfTokenServiceServlet.COOKIE_NAME_PARAM);
      }
      if (sessionCookieName == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
            XsrfTokenServiceServlet.COOKIE_NAME_NOT_SET_ERROR_MSG);
      }
    }
  }
```

The line throwing the exception is:

```
sessionCookieName = getServletConfig().getInitParameter(
          XsrfTokenServiceServlet.COOKIE_NAME_PARAM);
```

So the `getServletConfig()` method must be returning null at the time that the application context is being loaded up. There are probably ways around this where you could ensure that the bean is not "wired in" before the servlet config exists, however, in your case there is a simple solution. Since the servlet config and context are only required to access the cookie name if it is null, you can bypass this by specifying the cookie name in the constructor, i.e:

```
public XsrfProtectedServiceServlet(String sessionCookieName) {
    this.sessionCookieName = sessionCookieName;
}
```

So in your case in MyServiceImpl you would add:

```
public MyServiceImpl() {
   super("NAME_OF_THE_COOKIE_YOU_ARE_SPECIFYING_IN_WEB_XML_PROBABLY_JSESSIONID");
}
```